# Javascript: Checking for matching properties, arrow function won't update i in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, arrow-functions

I want to check for the existence of an object property that's inside of an array so that I can assemble a list of unique `room`s with a list of `time`s (pair of strings in this case). I haven't found a concise way to model this procedure outside of trivial arrays of numbers.

I attempted to loop through the list to check if the list I was inserting into already contained a matching class field, unfortunately, the variable `i` won't update in the function I passed into `findIndex()`

```js
const getClassroomList = (list) => {
  const temp = [{
    classroom: '',
    times: [{
      start_time: '',
      end_time: '',
    }],
  }];
  // For every classroom in list, check if classroom already exists.
  // If it does, add object to array
  // Else add pair of times to existing classroom
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
    const idx = list.findIndex((room) => {
      // console.log(i); Here the variable i won't update so the below fails
      return room.classroom === list[i].classroom;
    });
    if (idx === -1) {
      temp.push({
        classroom: list[i].classroom,
        times: [{
          start_time: list[i].start_time,
          end_time: list[i].end_time,
        }],
      });
    } else {
      temp[idx].times.push({
        start_time: list[i].start_time,
        end_time: list[i].end_time,
      });
    }
  }
  return temp;
};
```

It seems that the function initializes itself with the first instance of `i` it sees and keeps it at `0` when I want it to keep incrementing. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Works for me? https://jsbin.com/sicesadipu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll just close the question here as I made the stupid little error of using `findIndex()` on `list` instead of `temp`.

```js
const idx = list.findIndex((room) => {
  return room.classroom === list[i].classroom;
});
```

Fixed excerpt.

```js
const idx = temp.findIndex(room => room.classroom === list[i].classroom);
```